# Incompatible types in assignment of int [3] to unsigned int [100]

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors

In my header file (IntegerSet.h) the class is defined like so:

```
class IntegerSet{
public:
unsigned int set[100];
};
```

In my implementation file (IntegerSet.cpp) I created an `unsigned int` like so, and have the following code:

```
unsigned int newUnion[4];
IntegerSet c;
c.set=newUnion;
```

The problem is that whenever I try to compile the implementation file it returns the following error: `incompatible types in assignment of unsigned int [4] to unsigned int [100]`

Comment: Variables can't change their type at runtime. Even if they were the same type, arrays are unfortunately not assignable. `std::array` and `std::vector` are perfectly assignable.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Why do you affect a 4-elements arry to a 100 elements one? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @meneldal I'm trying to assign any objects array 'set' to a new and different array.

Comment: Arrays can't be affected in C/C++. You can think of them as constant pointers with allocated memory on the stack (so destroyed when they go out of scope). Please note the constant pointers and not pointers on constant because those are two very different things. You can however use `std::vector` or pointers (but in the later case careful about memory leaks) for what you need to do.

Comment: @meneldal Ahh I understand now. I think I'm just going to use vectors instead, it reminds me of Java arrays which I feel more comfortable with. Thanks for your help!